# Laravel Eloquent: How get the 3rd model using first model that only connects by the 2nd model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have User, Role and Permission model. User's have relation only with role and role to permission only, so Users and permissions have no connection between.

**Role model**

```
public function users(){
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'role_user', 'user_id', 'role_id');
}

public function permissions(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Permission', 'permission_role', 'permission_id', 'role_id');
}
```

**User model**

```
public function roles(){
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'role_user', 'user_id', 'role_id');
}
```

**Permission model**

```
public function roles(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'permission_role', 'permission_id', 'role_id');
}
```

So I'm able to get the users role if I do

```
$users->roles
```

Now how can I get the users role permissions directly using my User model which connected only with roles and roles that only one who connects with permission

```
$users->role()->permission
```

Comment: [`hasManyThrough`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) looks like exactly what you need

Comment: @apokryfos Is it possible make an inverse using this as well? Like permission to user instead of user to permission

Comment: In the docs example Country has many posts via users and Posts belong to many countries via users as well. I'd expect both directions to work equally well with `hasManyThrough`

Comment: Okay I got it thanks

Comment: actually for your case i think you should have a pivot table called permission_role and then if a user can have many roles than a role_user pivot table as well otherwise as User and Role is one to many ( 1 role can belong to many user ) so a belongsTo in User model and a hasMany in Role model.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to just display the permissions on the user's profile, for example, a nested foreach will do the trick:

```
<p class="strong">Roles:</p>
    <ul class="list-group">
        @foreach ($user->roles as $role)
            <li class="list-unstyled">{{ Html::link(url('/roles/'.$role->id),$role->label) }}</li>
            <ul class="list-group">
                @foreach ($role->permissions as $permission)
                    <li class="list-unstyled">{{ Html::link(url('/permissions/'.$permission->id),$permission->label) }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel provides a `hasManyThrough` method which is exactly what you need. The "has-many-through" relationship provides a convenient shortcut for accessing distant relations via an intermediate relation. For example, a Country model might have many Post models through an intermediate User model. With the help of this method, you can easily gather all blog posts for a given country. You can learn more about this relationship in the official docs:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0):

`hasManyThrough` will not work with many-to-many relationships. You can use nested `whereHas()` to get permissions for authenticated user:

```
Permission::whereHas('roles', function ($q) {
    $q->whereHas('users', function ($q) {
        $q->where('id', auth()->id());
    })
})->get();
```

And in the comments, you've asked about an inversed solution. If you want to get all users for specified permission, do this:

```
User::whereHas('roles', function ($q) use($permissionName) {
    $q->whereHas('permissions', function ($q) use($permissionName) {
        $q->where('name', $permissionName);
    })
})->get();
```